# Can I use Python 2 packages in a virtual environment that runs on Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I've deployed a Django app in a `virtualenv` that uses Python 3 as interpreter. This worked great until I needed a `pip` package that was written for Python 2. Is there a good way to use Python 2 packages within a Python 3 environment? I know that there's an [interoperability library](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) out there that might be able to help, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I guess my question would be what exactly is failing? Is it when you're trying to import a pkg or is it when you're writing your own python code? If you're writing your own code you can just use the `six` package like you mentioned. But if you're trying to use a package someone else wrote then you might want to consider checking if that package has python3 compatibility or just move to python2 to complete your project

Comment: I wanted to experiment with MongoDB so I tried to install [django-mongodb-engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) through `pip`. Among other things I got a syntax error on a `print` statement, which is how I discovered that this was Python 2 code. To the best of my knowledge they [haven't made any progress](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/179) porting their code to Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, probably not... I think this website should help you: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3
If you really want to use it you can port this package.